# Adapt width of dt and dd to content in dl-horizontal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap I would like to get a responsive definition list with `.dl-horizontal`. The width of the `dt` should adapt to the maximum length of its contents, while the `dd` should take the rest of the width.

This works on a [wide screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIVl3.png), but when the screen width is reduced, the margin to the left of the `dd` [stays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFNaA.png) (since it's defined like that in the CSS). This should somehow become zero when `td` and `dd` are stacked, but `margin-left: auto;` makes the `dd` text appear over the `td`.

HTML:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
<dt>Soup</dt>
<dd>
<ul>
<li>Mushroom </li>
</ul>
</dd>
...
<dt>Desserts</dt>
<dd>
<ul>
<li>Apple crumble </li>
<li>Cold Dessert of the Day </li>
<li>Natural yoghurt with fruit and nuts </li>
</ul>
</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
.dl-horizontal dt {
    width: auto;
}

.dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `float:left;` to your dt will resolve the issue. If you use web inspector, over 768px the class applied a float: left;

[See here for what I mean](https://www.bootply.com/NJtQgyQf4u). If you click the mobile icon, or scale in the window, it'll appear.

Below is the answer to your question in the comments. For what you want, you'll need to use media queries to resolve when margins should and shouldn't exist. The first option is ideal, as you're telling the browser when to add the margin. The second answer is you're telling the browser when to not add the margin. `768px` is generally when tablet sizes start, which is why I am adding in the margin at that, or which is why I am saying the margin is 0 before it hits that part.

```
@media all and ( min-width: 768px ) {
    .dl-horizontal dd { margin-left: 3em; }
}
```

or

```
@media all and ( max-width: 767px ) {
    .dl-horizontal dd { margin-left: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that already looks a lot nicer. However, what I would like is that the `dd` stacks below the `dt` on mobile, but that it starts on the left just below the `dt` (without a margin). Is that possible?

Comment: What you'll want to do is one of two things. I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, that indeed gives me what I want!

Comment: Glad that worked out for you! [Here's a link for more information, as well as a great website for insights and content on working with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)